# Saving document file in SQL Server database using vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

Please I need your help. I am trying to save a file in a SQL Server database, but it is showing this error

> Implicit conversion from data type varchar to varbinary(max) is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

Here is my code

```
  Private Sub Button70_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button70.Click
    fna = content.Text
    fna.Split("\")
    ffn = fna.Last.ToString

    conn.Open()
    Dim com As New SqlCommand
    com.Connection = conn
    com.CommandText = "insert into meeting (Date_Entry, Title, Chairperson, Venue, File_Name, [Content]) values( '" & date5.Text & "', '" & title.Text & "', '" & cp.Text & "', '" & vn.Text & "', '" & f_name.Text & "', '@[Content]')"
    With com.Parameters

        .AddWithValue("Content", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = File.ReadAllBytes(content.Text)
    End With
    com.ExecuteNonQuery()
    conn.Close()
    MsgBox("File saved")
    content.Clear()


End Sub

Private Sub Button25_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button25.Click
    '// open dilogue to add file to save
    If op.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        content.Text = op.FileName

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you explain why you use a parameter only for the last value? Use parameters ALWAYS.

Comment: For starters, `'@[Content]'` is passing in the literal varchar value '@[Content]', not the value of the parameter.  You need `@Content` without the quotes and brackets.

Comment: I can explain better in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168055/personal-chats).You can join me if you want :)

Comment: @PaulAbbott that's not only a wrong parameter placeholder, but it is also the cause of the error. The field expects a varbinary but it gets the varchar of '@[Content]'. You could post that as an answer.

Comment: .AddWithValue takes a string as the parameter name and an object as the value of the parameter not the datatype. The usage here looks like Parameters.Add not .AddWithValue

Comment: thank you so much @PaulAbbott that was the error i think course now its working

Answer (score 0):

You should use `@Content` instead of `@[Content]` in your query string.